# Height adjust to content in TableView cell?

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I am fairly new to Swift and I stumbled upon a problem. I fetch some JSON data and show it in a TableView, but the problem is that every cell can have n numbers of labels under each other (from the JSON(, so the cells needs to have different amount of content. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: I can't really get it to work, Im doing this to add more labels when the tableview is created. In my custom cell.

```
func addViews() {
     let rect = CGRect(x: 6, y: 10, width: containerView.frame.width-12, height: 90)
     containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

     let view1 = UIView(frame: rect)
     view1.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
     view1.layer.masksToBounds = false
     view1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
     view1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
     view1.layer.cornerRadius = 2
     view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

     var x = 2 as CGFloat
     var y = 2 as CGFloat
     var position = CGPointMake(x, y)
     i in 1...5 {
         let recti = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 50, height: 50)
         let s = UILabel(frame: recti)
         s.text = "\(i)"
         y = y + 20
         view1.addSubview(s)
         print(i)
     }
     containerView.addSubview(view1)  
}
```

And I've added these two lines to my TableViewController

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

But it doesn't adjust, and only shows the first label before it cuts the cell off.

Answer (score 3):

Setup your labels in your custom cell class, then use `cellForRow` for send it the data.

```
import UIKit


class cellClass: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!


func addViews(jsonStuff: [String]){

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20)
    var x = 50 as CGFloat
    let y = 20.0 as CGFloat

    var position = CGPointMake(x, y)

    for str in jsonStuff{

        let label = UILabel(frame: rect)
        label.text = str
        label.center = position
        containerView.addSubview(label)
        x = x + 40
        //y = y + 20
        position = CGPointMake(x,y)

    }


}





}



class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,       UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

var stringStuff = ["this", "that", "tje", "blah", "hey"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return stringStuff.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as!      cellClass
    if indexPath.row < 2{
        let sub = stringStuff[0...2]
        cell.addViews(Array(sub))
    }else{
        cell.addViews(stringStuff)
    }


    return cell
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

}
```

[image]

This is probably a giant hack, and I'm sure there are better ways, but here is some functional code that will dynamically size the row without using autolayout or predefined labels. You will probably have to play around with the rect heights to get everything looking right, and the remove subviews in cellForRowAtIndexPath is needed for cell reuse.

```
class cellClass: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

func addViews(lbsToAdd: Int) {

    let rctHeight = Int((5 + (lbsToAdd * 20)))

    let rect = CGRect(x: 6, y: 10, width: Int(containerView.frame.width-12), height: rctHeight)

    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    let view1 = UIView(frame: rect)
    view1.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    view1.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    view1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
    view1.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let x = 2 as CGFloat
    var y = 0 as CGFloat

    for i in 1...lbsToAdd {
        let recti = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 50, height: 20)
        let s = UILabel(frame: recti)
        s.text = "\(i)"
        y = y + 20
        containerView.frame.size.height = containerView.frame.size.height + 20
        view1.addSubview(s)
        print(i)
    }

    containerView.addSubview(view1)

}


}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var testTable: UITableView!

var stringStuff = ["Jetta", "< Golf >", "Passat", "CC", "Beetle", "Ford", "Chevy", "Nissan"]
let labelsCount = 10

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    testTable.delegate = self
    testTable.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stringStuff.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let total = ((Int(indexPath.row) + 2) * 2)


        return CGFloat(total * labelsCount)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? cellClass

    cell?.containerView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })


    cell?.addViews(indexPath.row + 1)

    return cell!
}


}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm more curious about how I create the labels dynamically? I can't just add the label to the cell in the storyboard, since I'll, for example, need two labels in one cell and 8 in the other.

Comment: Create a function in your custom cell class to generate n amount of labels. Then just run some code like this in a for loop `var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, number, 200, 21))
    label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = "I'am a test label"
    self.view.addSubview(label)`

Comment: I'll try that! But I need to create n number of labels according to the number of certain data I get in from the JSON, how can I get that when creating the labels, in my custom cell class?

Comment: I've updated my answer above, setting the constraints will take some patients but the above is the general idea. In the `cellForRow` you can  place an `if` statement to decide what data to send to the cell class. That would allow you to control the amount of labels in each cell independently.

Comment: That makes sense! I'll try that out. @NRitH How would you do it without code?

Comment: I added an `if` check to the example code. It will send just a portion of the array depending on the row index. You could use whatever check you needed in order to send the right amount of data to the cell class.

Comment: I've added to my question, could you be of assistance?

Comment: @Recusiwe , I've added some code to my previous answer that handles dynamic row sizes without autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't you update the view1 height after you increment your UILabel, try this:

```
func addViews() {
     let rect = CGRect(x: 6, y: 10, width: containerView.frame.width-12, height: 90)
     containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()



    let view1 = UIView(frame: rect)
     view1.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
     view1.layer.masksToBounds = false
     view1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
     view1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
     view1.layer.cornerRadius = 2
     view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
     var containerViewHeight = 0 // height for view1
     var x = 2 as CGFloat
     var y = 2 as CGFloat
     var position = CGPointMake(x, y)

     i in 1...5 {
         let recti = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 50, height: 50)
         let s = UILabel(frame: recti)
         s.text = "\(i)"
         y = y + 20
         view1.addSubview(s)
         containerViewHeight += 50 //your label height
         print(i)
     }
     view1.bounds.size.height = CGFloat(containerViewHeight) // set height
     containerView.addSubview(view1)  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, examine your JSON for that indexPath and figure out the required height for that cell. Then the table view will size the row to match your dynamic content.

[Here is a link to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is used when you've set your `UITableViewCell` with Auto-layouts. and you did not set any.

You have two general ways to achieve this:

**Handle It In Code**

You know how much height one label needs, so in `rowForHeightAtIndexPath` return `expectedHeightForOneLabel * numberOfLabels`

**StackView + Autol-layout**

If you're developing for iOS 9.0+, use `UIStackView` with `stackView.axis = .Vertical`, set Auto-layout for your stackView and set `stackView.distribution = .FillProportionally`, Then start adding labels tu it.